# How to get most frequently repeated object in a n-n relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have these 2 entities (in C# and EntityFramework):

```
public class Article 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

which have a n-n relationship. I'm loading my articles as simple as you can see in this snippet:

```
var model = _context.Articles
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(a => a.Tags)
                    .ToList();
```

Now, I'm trying to get `Tag`s which are most repeated in articles by this snippet:

```
var tags = model.SelectMany(a => a.Tags)
                .GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.Articles })
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .Take(10);
```

But it seems doesn't work (I'm getting Count = 1 for all tags). What am I missing here? Any idea please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your concrete question:

> But it seems doesn't work (I'm getting Count = 1 for all tags). What am I missing here?

This is because you have included `tag.Articles` into the grouping key. Normally it would not be a problem (except the redundancy and unnecessary comparisons) if the `Tag` objects with the same `Id` were sharing one and the same instance. But since you have populated the `model` using no tracking query (`.AsNoTracking()`), the `Tag` objects representing one and the same record are actually different instances (with data duplicated), so is their `Articles` list, hence the group by does not work as expected. It can easily be seen by the following snippet:

```
foreach (var tagGroup in model.SelectMany(a => a.Tags).GroupBy(t => t.Id))
{
    Tag prevTag = null;
    foreach (var tag in tagGroup)
    {
        if (prevTag != null) Debug.Assert(prevTag == tag); // FAIL!
        prevTag = tag;
    }
}
```

To fix the issue, either remove `AsNotracking` or exclude `Articles` from the grouping key:

```
var tags = model.SelectMany(a => a.Tags)
                .GroupBy(t => t.Id) // or Name
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are interested in is `Article`s by `Tag`s then why not select the other way round:

```
var model = _context.Tags.AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(t => t.Articles)
                    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Articles.Count())
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a small addition to Gilad Green's answer, here is a little program that fills in a sample set, then selects the first 100 tags, that are most present in articles

```
class Program
{
    public class Article
    {
        public Article()
        {
            Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public Tag()
        {
            Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
        List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();

        int n = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            tags.Add(new Tag() { Id = i });
        }

        int v = 100;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
        {
            var article = new Article() { Id = i };

            int c = rnd.Next(1,v);

            for (int k = 0; k < c; k++)
            {
                var tag = tags[rnd.Next(0, v - 1)];

                article.Tags.Add(tag);
                tag.Articles.Add(article);
            }

            articles.Add(article);
        }


        var orderedbyarticles = tags.OrderBy(x => x.Articles.Count).Take(100).ToList();

        foreach(var item in orderedbyarticles)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.Id);    
        }

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```